# DidUpdateLocation not storing location, userLoc always nil

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to simply get the user's current device location and store it in a global variable called userLoc. I have this code to call didUpdateLocation:

```
self.locationManager.requestLocation()
print("aaa ", self.userLoc)
```

and this to set the userLoc to the current location:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            self.userLoc = location
        }
    }
```

userLoc is defined like this:

```
var userLoc: CLLocation?
```

but when I run the app and try to print userLoc, it ALWAYS prints:

```
aaa nil
```

The `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` is set in the Info.plist. I honestly dont know what else to try. I've been banging my head against the wall for a while trying to fix this. Any help you could give would be very much appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Your `print` line is being called long before the location is updated.

Comment: How long does it usually take to update the location? I've thought that, but I've also tried putting in a `sleep` for a couple seconds to see if it gives it time to update. Nothing

Comment: Do use `sleep`, especially from the main thread. Simply move your `print` to just after the line where you set `self.userLoc`. And also check the console for any messages related to missing privacy settings. And make sure you have a call to `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization`. There are many samples and tutorials on how to properly work with CoreLocation.

Comment: I've always ended up using locations.first ...not sure if that matters though.

Comment: When I do what you recommended, the userLoc prints, but when I try to reference userLoc it crashes becasue userLoc is still nil. And when I try the line `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization` i get an error: `Expression resolves to an unused function`

Comment: It's a function. You forget the `()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to get user location within my view controller class. I think you are missing `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`:

```
var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
currentLocation = locationManager.location!.coordinate
```